# CSV Sorting on only particular columns

Tags: shell, csv

So ive been presented with this comma-delimited file:
I need a print to look as below
"
lastname, phone_number, zip

for every person with a last name starting with the letter H, I

only with a 650-area code phone number. output should be sorted by reverse ZIP code "

I only have four columns, for example:

```
Harris, K, (650)345-1760 1200, Ellis Street Suite 230 Mountain CA 93042
Mitchell, A, (212)-555-1234 650, This Street NY NY 01234
Thomson, F, (650)-999-9999 1450, The Terrace Avenue Stratford MA 10101
irvin, h, (650)678-2445 12345, denver st santa clara 96503
```

I thought I was on the right path with this code:

```
cat data.csv | awk -F"," '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}' |sort -t ',' -k1|grep "(650)"
```

then to try to grep just the last name's first letter only...

```
cat data.csv | awk -F "," '$1~/"H*"/' '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}'
```

but keep getting errors.
How can I search for just the first letter as well as only part of a string in the last column and reverse order that?(I imagine with sort?)

Comment: I'm not familiar with US zip codes but is the state (CA, MA) part of the zip code or just the numbers?

Comment: edit your posting to include the errors you're getting. Are you sure your file is saved with Unix line endings? Use `dos2unix filename` to be sure. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [r17](http://www.rseventeen.com/examples/) , which is a tool which could help with your task.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F', ' '
    toupper($1) ~ /^[HI]/ && $3 ~ /^\(650\)/ {
        n = split($NF, ary, " ")
        print ary[n] ":" $0
    }
' filename |
sort -rn |
cut -d: -f2-
```

produces

```
irvin, h, (650)678-2445 12345, denver st santa clara 96503
Harris, K, (650)345-1760 1200, Ellis Street Suite 230 Mountain CA 93042
```